# How can we find the answer to this equation using python?

Tags: python, math, sympy, algebra

Hello I'm kinda new to the mathematics side of Python and I was trying out ways to solve an equation which is:

```
a * (10**(n-1)) + x = y*x
```

where 'y' and 'n' are known and we have to find 'x' and 'a'. Now I've tried something which returns an equation to me rather than values:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import symbols, Eq

def remove_first_digit(n, y):
    a, x = symbols("a,x", integer=True)
    equation = Eq((10 ** (n-1)), ((y-1)*x)/a)
    return solve(equation, (x,a))
print(remove_first_digit(2, 7))
```

I'm expecting values 'a' = 3 and 'x' = 5.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The problem here is pure math, not programming. You have no reason to expect those values you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is x = 5*a/3 or a = 3*x/5, any combination of numbers that satisfies this will work, not just 3 and 5, your program works perfectly. You need to do further operations to reduce the possible answers if you want a = 3 and x = 5.

Comment: Just as a note, there is never a single answer when the number of equations is less than the number of unknowns.  You have 1 equation with 2 unknowns.  To get a single answer, you need another equation.

Comment: Heyy thanks for the answer. Just another question, how should I proceed for the further operations? It will be of great help. :)

Comment: I haven't used sympy, but it seems to return the answer as a pair, one is a variable and one is a multiplication involving the variable. To get just one answer, it's as easy as setting that one variable to anything and then solving for the other one.